# Spring Boot Webflux + Elastic APM Monitoring

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, elastic-apm

I am currently new to Elastic APM.
I am currently developing an application using spring-webflux and want to monitor my application using Elastic APM, but unfortunately, it's not working for me.

Dependecies

```
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

APM Java Agent Version -  1.8.0
Elastic search - 7.2.0
APM server - 7.2.0

Exception observed -

```
2020-05-07 00:03:31.529 [main] INFO co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.ErrorLoggingListener - org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext refers to a missing class
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve type description for javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Resolution$Illegal.resolve(TypePool.java:159)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$LazyTypeDescription$TokenizedGenericType.toErasure(TypePool.java:6241)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$LazyTypeDescription$GenericTypeToken$Resolution$Raw$RawAnnotatedType.of(TypePool.java:3412)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$LazyTypeDescription$GenericTypeToken$Resolution$Raw.resolveReturnType(TypePool.java:3302)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$LazyTypeDescription$LazyMethodDescription.getReturnType(TypePool.java:6796)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asSignatureToken(MethodDescription.java:838)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.FailSafeDeclaredMethodsCompiler.compile(FailSafeDeclaredMethodsCompiler.java:85)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.bci.bytebuddy.FailSafeDeclaredMethodsCompiler.compile(FailSafeDeclaredMethodsCompiler.java:66)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default.prepare(MethodRegistry.java:471)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:198)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.doTransform(AgentBuilder.java:10327)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:10263)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.access$1600(AgentBuilder.java:10029)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:10648)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:10595)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:10186)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition$ClassNameFilter.isPresent(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnWebApplicationCondition.getOutcome(OnWebApplicationCondition.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnWebApplicationCondition.getOutcomes(OnWebApplicationCondition.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.match(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.filter(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:396)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.dhisco.hotel.search.HotelSearchApp.main(HotelSearchApp.java:14)
```

Could someone please suggest what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no support from elastic for WebFlux yet

Check here https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/issues/60

They are currently working on it, but there is not a date to be ready yet

Answer (score 5):

Elastic APM now supports Webflux (either Tomcat or Netty):
https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/pull/1305

Since Elastic APM 1.25.0, this is enabled by setting `enable_experimental_instrumentations` to `true`, either in `elasticapm.properties`, or as JVM argument:

```
enable_experimental_instrumentations=true
```

Before this, it was enabled by setting `disable_instrumentations` to empty string:

```
disable_instrumentations=
```

https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/issues/60#issuecomment-822419013

```
Features
Test application:

available as an executable jar and also used for unit-testing instrumentation
provides both functional and annotated controllers endpoints
executable with netty or tomcat as server, which allows to cover Webflux with or without Servlets
provides a client to call itself (based on Webflux client), thus using any third-party HTTP client is not necessary
Instrumentation:

Webflux server: covers both functional and annotated endpoints variants
Webflux client: not covered yet, see add support for Webflux client instrumentation #1306
using new plugin API and indy dispatcher.
adds reactor instrumentation for context-propagation
```

Answer (score 0):

WebFlux can run on Servlet containers with support for the Servlet 3.1 Non-Blocking IO API as well as on other async runtimes such as **Netty** and Undertow.

Each Spring Boot web application includes an embedded web server.

For reactive stack applications, the `spring-boot-starter-webflux` includes Reactor Netty by default I guess. And it does not include `Servlet API` (Netty is non-Servlet runtime), but it looks like your `Elastic APM` expects this API to be present.

Try to use `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` instead of Netty. When [switching to a different HTTP server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html), you need to exclude the default dependencies in addition to including the one you need.

Here is an example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Netty dependency -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Use Tomcat instead -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Tomcat dependency brings Servlet API. Perhaps it will resolve your issue.