# Spring Cloud Sleuth with Elastic APM

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, project-reactor, spring-cloud-sleuth, elastic-apm

Is it possible of providing the Tracers and Spans of Spring Cloud Sleuth (for a Webflux project) to Elastic APM?

I've seen a discussion of the [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642883/spring-boot-webflux-elastic-apm-monitoring) in the context of Spring Webflux. And [here in the context of Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://github.com/elastic/apm/issues/116).